# How to write a CTE to aggregate hierarchical values

Tags: sql, sqlite, common-table-expression

I want to write expressions in sqlite to process a tree of items, starting with the leaf nodes (the bottom) and proceeding back to their parents all the way to the root node (the top), such that each parent node is updated based on the content of its children. I've been able to write a CTE that does something similar, but isn't yet totally correct.

I have a simple table "test1" containing some nested values:

```
id | parent | value | total
---+--------+--------------
1  | NULL   | NULL  | NULL
2  | 1      | NULL  | NULL
3  | 2      | NULL  | NULL
4  | 3      | 50    | NULL
5  | 3      | 50    | NULL
6  | 2      | 60    | NULL
7  | 6      | 90    | NULL
8  | 6      | 60    | NULL
```

Rows may have children who reference their parent via their `parent` field. Rows may have a value of their own as well as child rows, or they may simply be parents without values (ie. "wrappers"). The leafs would be the rows without any children.

For each row I'd like to calculate the `total`, as the average or the row's  `value` (if not null) AND its children's `total`s. This should start with the leaf nodes and proceed up the tree to their parents, all the way to the root node at the top of the data hierarchy.

I've tried a number of variations of CTE's but am having difficulty writing one that will recursively calculate these totals from the bottom up.

Currently, I have:

```
UPDATE test1 SET total = (
  WITH RECURSIVE cte(cte_id,cte_parent,cte_value,cte_total) AS (
    SELECT test1.id, test1.parent, test1.value, test1.total
      UNION ALL
    select t.id, t.parent, t.value, t.total from test1 t, cte
    WHERE cte.cte_id=t.parent
  ) SELECT AVG(cte_value) FROM cte
);
```

which produces:

```
id | parent | value | total
---+--------+-------+------
1  | NULL   | NULL  | 62
2  | 1      | NULL  | 62
3  | 2      | NULL  | 50
4  | 3      | 50    | 50
5  | 3      | 50    | 50
6  | 2      | 60    | 70
7  | 6      | 90    | 90
8  | 6      | 60    | 60
```

Looking at the top-most rows, this is not quite right, since it's taking an average of not only the row's immediate children, but of *all* the row's descendants. This causes row 2 for example to have a `total` of 62 instead of 60.  The expected results should set rows 2's total to 60, as the average of its immediate child rows 3 and 6. Row 1's total would be 60 as well.

How can I calculate a "total" value for each row based on an average of the row's value and the values of it's immediate children only, while ensuring the upper levels of the hierarchy are correctly populated based on the calculated totals of their children?

Comment: What are your expected results?  and if you're only going 1 level deep... why use a recursive query; just join...

Comment: It's not that it absolutely has to be done recursively, but in trying a simple update, sqlite takes a very top-down approach as one might expect, leading to the total column being populated on the basis of as-yet-uncalculated child totals. PS. Clarified the expected results.

Comment: So why is row 1's total expected to be 60.  It's NULL value + children (row 2 whose value is null as well Null+null = null...  Row 2 has 2 children rows 3 and 6.  NULL+60+Null for itself means the avg would be 20 right?  or since we have two nulls they aren't included in the avg.... I'm struggling with the math/formula on this. so complete expected results for your example would help.

Comment: The total values of the upper levels of the hierarchy should be predicated on it's immediate children having already had their totals correctly calculated and set. This is why the question specified "bottom up".

Comment: I get it now which is why a Recursive query now makes sense...

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? A recursive CTE to do bottom-up traversal of a nested hierarchy is a totally valid technical question with practically no documented examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out that a very similar question and solution was posted here:

[How can I traverse a tree bottom-up to calculate a (weighted) average of node values in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41376655/how-can-i-traverse-a-tree-bottom-up-to-calculate-a-weighted-average-of-node-va)

Since sqlite3 doesn't let you create functions, the example using a recursive CTE applies:

```
with recursive cte(id, parent, value, level, total) as (
    select
        t.id, t.parent, t.value,
        0,
        t.value as total
    from test1 t
    where not exists (
        select id
        from test1
        where parent = t.id)
union all
    select
        t.id, t.parent, t.value,
        c.level+1,
        case when t.value is null then c.total else t.value end
    from test1 t
    join cte c on t.id=c.parent
)
select id, parent, value, avg(total) total from (
    select
        id, parent, value, level, avg(total) total
        from cte
        group by id,parent,level
)
group by id, parent
order by id
```